# Why I am getting this decimal int in this char?

Tags: c, byte

I am starting C before learned Python and i am having some doubts in some concepts.

I am running this example in a 64-bit machine.

```
/* I  understand that "vid" is only a char like any other else not a array of char 
   and its sizeof is 1 byte. The decimal int is 100 and the char is 'D'. 
   Why? 'vid' does not exist in ASCII table. How does the compiler leads with that */

   char name = "vid";

/* sizeof is 8 bytes. I am not sure because if char is int therefore an array 
of char would 
be an array of int and if so int takes 2 or 4 bytes storage size so we reach that is 
3 char long plus the NULL byte ('\0') we get 3 * 2 bytes + 1 * 2 bytes = 8 bytes . 
Am i correct? And why we need to use * to declare it? Does * is not for pointers? 
How does this syntax works? */

  char *name_ = "vid";
```

Comment: `"vid"` is a `char[4] = {'v','i','d','\0'}` and on the right side of `=` it is `char *` (adress of first character `v`). On 64-bit machines, adresses are 64 bit big integers. `char` only 8 bit. So you cast a 64 bit memory cell to 8 bit. Like `int d = nnn; char name = d;`. Value of name depends on how overflow is managed.

Comment: You are simply mixing up `"string"` and `'c'`. The first is a string literal, a nul-terminated array of `char`, the second is a integer character constant. You should read up some basic stuff about the base types in C.

Answer (score 2):

1. A string constant like `"vid"` decays into a pointer to its first byte, and when you convert a pointer to a `char`, the program will truncate the pointer's value to make it fit. Apparently, that happens to produce a number whose ASCII value is `D` on your machine. You get an `initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast` warning for that, if you compile with GCC.
2. `sizeof(name_) == sizeof(char*)`, which is 8 on a machine with 64-bit pointers. `sizeof("vid") == 4`, per definition: `sizeof` measures size in `char` units.

Answer (score 1):

In the first exemple `name = "vid"` you are not assigning the string `"vid"` to name, by convension, a string constant is a pointer to it's first element, so in the first statment you're assigning the address of `"vid"`. Like others said by accident the number stored in `name` after the address gets fitted to 1 bytes was the ascii code of `'D'`. But if you turn on warnings you will get an error message telling you that your tring to assigne make a `char` from `char *` which is not compatible as `char` can hold only 1 byte.

The second exemple `char *name_ = "vid"` your assigning the address of `"vid"` to `name_` which is right as it is a pointer to `char`.

Note that you are not storing the string `"vid"` in `name_`. The string constant `"vid"` is stored somewhere in a read only memory and the address of the first element of that string constant is assigned to `name_`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, I am not sure how that compiles.  You are attempting to assign an array of characters to a single character.  This shouldn't be allowed without some kind of warning.

For the second, you are taking `sizeof` a `char*`, which is a pointer.  Anytime you add the `*` to a type, you make it a pointer.  In your case, this is 8 bytes, regardless of how much data it is pointing to.  If you want to know the size of the data and not the size of the pointer, then you'd need to do the following;

```
sizeof(name_[0]) * 4
```

or

```
sizeof(char) * 4
```

Since your array is 3 characters, +1 for the null character, making it 4 characters long.  This takes the size of the first element (a single character, 1 byte) and multiplies it by the length of the string.  Thus, your data size should be 4 bytes.

Comment: His 1st example will compile with an warning. `warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: You never need to compute `sizeof(char)`. It is guaranteed to be `1`, because `sizeof` measures in `char`-sized units.

Answer (score 0):

Your first string of code declares `name` as a pointer to an array of four characters placed in static data segment. So when you are treating name as a character you get the last byte of the pointer: 0x??????????????64 where '??' are unknown bytes.

About the second string, you're getting sizeof of the pointer. In 64-bit systems pointers are 64-bit or 8-byte. It is what you get.